# Topological form of Martin's Axiom

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I'm currently studying consequences of Martin's Axiom:

Martin's Axiom (MA): Suppose that $\left\langle P, \leq \right\rangle$ is a ccc partially ordered set and $\{D_\alpha\}_{\alpha < \lambda}$ is a family of dense subsets of $P$, with $\lambda < 2^{\aleph_0}$. Then there is a compatible subset $Q \subseteq P$ such that
$$Q \cap D_\alpha \neq \varnothing, \forall \alpha < \lambda.$$

MA has a (equivalent) topological form, namely:

(1) Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff ccc space. Then $K$ is not the union of less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ nowhere dense sets.

I can show that MA implies (1). However, I'm having trouble showing the reverse implication, namely that (1) implies MA. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Show that you can assume that $P$ is separative, and show that in that case if $P$ is ccc, then its Boolean completion is ccc. Now recall Stone's representation theorem; and use (1) to conclude that given ${<}2^{\aleph_0}$ dense open sets, their intersection is non-empty, and so you can find the wanted $Q$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look deeper into this.

Comment: Maybe you should accept this *after* you look deeper into this.